# Open-NetGPO fails on domain controller

Tags: powershell, networking, gpo

I am trying to use Open-NetGPO on my domain controller in order to enable Windows Defender Firewall through the GPO:

```
New-GPO -Name test | New-GPLink -Target "dc=experiment,dc=local"
$GpoSession = Open-NetGPO -PolicyStore experiment.local\test
Set-NetFirewallProfile -All -GpoSession $GpoSessionName -Enabled True
Save-NetGPO -GPOSession $GpoSession
```

But I receive the error:

```
Open-NetGPO : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:2 char:15
+ $GpoSession = Open-NetGPO -PolicyStore experiment.local\test
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetGPO:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetGPO)
    [Open-NetGPO], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,Open-NetGPO
```

When I run the script from the second line (because the first line can only work on a domain controller) on a different machine everything works fine.

What should be done differently in order for the whole script to run on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and "resolved" it by removing the registry value:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters\RegisterDnsARecords
```

and restarted the Netlogon service.